# No route matches [GET] /assets/images/header.jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails 5.0.0.1

in my css:

```
background-image: url('images/header.jpg');
```

file header.jpg place in: app/assets/images/header.jpg

```
error: No route matches [GET] /assets/images/header.jpg
```

Request URL: (in firefox): http://localhost:3000/assets/images/header.jpg 
Result code: 404

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put some image to your assets/images/somepics

then this is the code for html example

```
img alt="avatar" src="/assets/avatar.png" class="avatar"
```

Comment: <img alt="avatar" class="avatar-size" src="assets/images/avatar.png"></img> -> No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/avatar.png

Comment: solved: <img alt="avatar" class="avatar-size" src="assets/avatar.png"> and background-image: url('header.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url('login-bg1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: asset-url('login-bg1.jpg')
```